# creating new files in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How can I create new files using iPhone SDK? I would like to provide the file name and its extension.

Answer (score 1):

### In Xcode:

1. File >> New File...
2. Mac OSX >> Other >> Empty File
3. Name it anything you want.

### At Runtime:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: <(NSString*)path>
                                        contents: <(NSData*)contents> 
                                      attributes: <(NSDictionary*)attributes>];
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to save a custom object to a file within your application.

First, generate the **path** that you'll save your file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);   
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *docPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFileName.ext"];
```

Save with:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myObject toFile:docPath];
```

Retrieve with:

```
myObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:docPath];
```

Finally - your object has to implement the NSCoding protocol with the two functions that I list below.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject <NSCoding> {  
//other functions, variables, etc..   
    - (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder;    
    - (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder;  
}
```

Those functions inform iOS how to treat each one of your instance variables when it comes to retrieving or saving your object.
See more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Instead of `<code>...</code>` use an empty line + indentation with four spaces. This enables syntax coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create files on the file system of the iOS device?

In that case you might want to take a look at `NSFileHandle` and similar methods. Hard to say what would be the best to use in your case, since your question hardly reveals any details about what you want to achieve...